# Android 4.4.x screen rotation

Tags: android, screen, hardware, screen-orientation

I'm using Android 4.4.2, and my need is to revert the screen in landscape mode.

On the previous versions of Android I was able to do this simply setting

ro.sf.hwrotation=180

in build.prop file, under /system.

Searching with google I've discovered that with Android 4.4.x this option is no more availalbe (in fact it doesn't work) .

Does anyone know how to solve this issue in another way?

Thx

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your question so I evened the score. Hopefully you get an answer.